# Placing a diode between low and high beam on a motorcycle

Tags: switches

I am trying to place a diode between the high beam and low beam on my motorcycle. My headlight is a skull, it has the two eyes as high beam, and the mouth as low beam. the way it is wired, when you hit the high beam the eyes light up, and the low beam the mouth lights up. On high beam , I want them all on, and on low beam only the mouth. the eyes are each 50 watts, and the mouth is 55 watts. talking to the manufacturer, he stated that the eyes are each 4amps, and the mouth is 4.5 amps, giving me a total of 12.5 amps, my question is what diode do I need to perform this task? I know it has to be 12 volts, but that's all I know. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That sounds pretty bad-ass. You could use a diode, but you'll get heat and voltage drop. How about a 12V headlight relay?

Comment: never thought of that, I will have to look at that.My bike is for show, and I am trying not to place anything in eye sight. Thanks

Comment: How should your interface look? If you simply want a mechanical switch, consider using exactly that. If you don't find a switch with high enough current rating, you can switch a smaller signal mechanically and turn on a low resistance MOSFET with that. What voltage is your power supply? 
If you add enough info, I'll write a proper answer with a schematic tomorrow.

Comment: Given an actual maintenance schematic, you may often find actual relays on the newer motocycles to drive the lamps individually, just like in most post 80's cars, in which case a tiny little diode to control the relay from either switch position would be enough, since the current will be handled by the relays, not your diode. That's how I fixed it on my Bike before I put LED lights in (that's a whole new Ballgame). <-- Typed before I properly read you may be playing a different game with the demo bike....

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2gtif.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Addition of a relay.*

As Spehro points out a relay solves this nicely. Provided you can run a few wires you can hide the relay anywhere.

Note that your switch contact may not handle 12.5 A well. To keep it running with only 8 A as supplied, wire the relay contact from the *battery* rather than the high-beam wire.